# Maven(-exec-plugin) parses the * (asterisk) symbol

Tags: maven, special-characters, exec-maven-plugin

I'd like to use the `exec-maven-plugin` to execute some NPM based tasks.

I had a problem, where my arguments were not passed correctly, so I tried using a batch file, which outputs the passed arguments, as a debug.

I came to the conclusion, that arguments containing the `* (asterisk)` symbol were ignored completely. If I tried the symbol in itself, I got a list of files in the working directory passed as separate arguments.

How can I tell maven(-exec-plugin) to just pass the argument with the `*` symbol untouched?

The context doesn't really seem to matter here, but I'm not taking my chances. Here is my configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>E:\test.bat</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>src\main\java\&#42;&#42;\&#42;.css</argument>
                        <argument>--use autoprefixer</argument>
                        <argument>-d target</argument>
                        <argument>--base src\main\java</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

PS.: replacing `*` with `&#42;` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Using `commandlineArgs` instead of `arguments` solved the problem. The reason is unknown to me